# How does hashmap handle negative hashcode?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Hashcode has type of `int`, so it can be negative and positive.
But `HashMap` uses hashcode to determinate in which index of the table put key+value, like, 
`hashcode / size_of_table = table_index`.

But how `HashMap` will determinate in which index it should put key+value in case hashcode is negative?

Comment: Take a wild guess, it's not exactly a mystery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java:

```
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
    return h & (length-1);
}
```